# Ajax data parameters not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm calling a REST API with AJAX call, in this way:

```
function getPay(CF) {
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      data: {codFisc: CF},
      timeout: 6000,
      url: "http://192.168.40.129:8180/api/rest/done",
      success: function(data){
            var count = Object.keys(data).length;
            console.log(data);
            for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                resultList.push(data);
            }
...
...
```

In other calls this is working fine. Now i get no result with this AJAX call. If i remove data parameter and call the rest API with this url: `http://192.168.40.129:8180/api/rest/done?codFisc=XXX` then i get the results and all is working fine. Where am i doing wrong?

Comment: what is `CF`, is it a variable or a constant value? If its constant then put it in quotes `'CF'`

Comment: CF is a parameter of the function where AJAX call is done. (question edited) @AmanRawat

Comment: Is there any error on your browser console?

Comment: Did you try `data: { 'codFisc': CF }`. I dont know why but last time i faced a similar problem, this solved it.

Comment: I can not immediately see anything wrong with this code. Could you just for the fun of it try to add `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`? (I assume it is json since it is a REST API).

Comment: Have you added  `dataType: "json"` ?

Comment: Added dataType and contentType, not working. Console is not showing errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here Cf must be numeric. As it is working in by Query string

you can try this.

```
  function getPay(CF) {
  $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  data: {},
  timeout: 6000,
  url: "http://192.168.40.129:8180/api/rest/done?codFisc="+CF,
  success: function(data){
        var count = Object.keys(data).length;
        console.log(data);
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            resultList.push(data);
        }
```

....

Make sure return type of data from sever. if its a json obj then add dataType:'json'

You can also try this:

```
 function getPay(CF) {
   if (CF != null) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://192.168.40.129:8180/api/rest/done',
                data: { codFisc: CF },
                type: "GET",
                async: false,
                success: function (result) {
                 // show message
                 // do stuff here
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    // show message
                    ShowMessage(XMLHttpRequest.responseText, 'Error');
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            ShowMessage("Please select record to edit", 'Error');
            //record id is null
        }
        }
```

Comment: This is the only way to make it working, but i can't understand why i have a function that has the same code and it's working fine with the code i posted in question (url is different).

Comment: The way i'm using url query string .. and send empty in data part

Comment: You can aslo send data through body part the as you mentioned in your question , CF must have value try it .. see in your developer tool console.log value of CF

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      data: JSON.stringify({codFisc: CF}),
      timeout: 6000,
      url: "http://192.168.40.129:8180/api/rest/done",
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function(data){
            var count = Object.keys(data).length;
            console.log(data);
            for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                resultList.push(data);
            }
```